# Loading a Neo4j subgraph into Networkx

Tags: python, neo4j, networkx, graph-databases, subgraph

I have been dealing with Neo4j through python's Bulbflow and now need a way to save/export subgraphs. I have seen Java and even Ruby approaches for doing this, however a simple Python approach seems to be hiding from me..

So far, I have found two potential paths:

1. Accessing [Geoff](http://nigelsmall.com/geoff) through [py2neo](http://pythonhosted.org/py2neo/geoff.html), but there is surprisingly little documentation for extracting a subgraph from a big local neo4j database or from a neo4jserver.
2. Using [Networkx](http://networkx.github.com/):
   I found networkx can load graphs from many different formats (I am unsure which format neo4j stores their dbs), however I haven't found a way to extract a only a subgraph into Networkx. I assume this should be done from a gremlin query, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I have a preference for the Networkx path, as it also comes with network analysis algorithms I wish to apply to subgraphs. I feel it would also avoid potential clashes between Bulbflow and py2neo, although I'm not sure whether such a clash would exist.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I didn't know the answer until you asked, but it seems like you can just export in gml, which networkx can read. Here are a few answers that might be useful:

[Neo4j export Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871860/neo4j-export-tree)

[Convert Neo4j DB to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204440/convert-neo4j-db-to-xml)

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Gremlin-Methods

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but if you stumbled upon it like me - know that networkx has a [subgraph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html) command, so you can load the whole graph from Neo4j and use that.